# Convert DateTime to string according to Oracle Format Mask

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, formatting

There is an Oracle DB API function which expects as an input a string representing date (or in other cases number) which is formatted by the provided format mask.

Before I went and implemented Oracle Format Mask parser I thought I would ask whether there is a .net built-in or third party way of converting `DateTime` .net object to `string` using Oracle Format Mask?

*Update*

Examples:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string convertedDate = ConvertDateTimeToOracleFormattedString (date, "Month DD, YYYY"); // should produce: March 21, 2014
convertedDate = ConvertDateTimeToOracleFormattedString (date, "CC BC"); // should produce: 21
// any other valid oracle format combination: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924
```

My current idea is to parse provided Oracle Format Mask into equivalent .net custom date and time format string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx and use it when converting .net DateTime to string: `DateTime.Now.ToString ("equivalentDotNetFormat");`. The equivalent .net format of "Month DD, YYYY" would be "MMMM dd, yyyy". Unless there is a quicker approach.

Comment: Could you please include some test case that defines the input and output in your question?

Comment: [odp.net](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A96160_01/oratyp10.htm) contains  classes that transform dates to strings. I wonder if you can leverage that in your application.

Comment: @abhi After a quick test it seems like `odp.net` classes will provide functionality I need. Could you provide your comment as an answer so I can give you proper credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please take a look at [ODP .NET](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A96160_01/oratyp10.htm)?

I believe it has the necessary classes to provide you the functionality you desire.